# await for response and return non json

Tags: javascript, url, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I have this function where it parses a html and I want to use await on it, so that I can wait until the html parsing is loaded.

here is what I am using as of now to load the Html:

```
function loadHTMLSource(urlSource){ 
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhttp.open("GET", urlSource, false); 
    xhttp.send(); 
    return xhttp.response; 
}
```

I then take that function and do this with it...

```
var page_html = loadHTMLSource(url);

parser = new DOMParser()
my_document = parser.parseFromString(page_html, "text/html");
search_str = await item[1];
search_attr_name = "data-style-name"; 

var all_styles = my_document.querySelectorAll("[data-style-name]");
```

I dont really know why I put an await before Item 1 or if it even does anything at all but lets move on..

item[1] is basically a string value and it looks for that string value inside the html..

Except it seems as if the html data loads before I even have time to look at the page not even load it..

So I think that If I changed it to a async function it should work...

Except this is not a JSON response.. so How would I do this using  async and await... ?

I appreciate your Help Thank you..

Comment: if you want Ajax + Promises, check out the newer [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) api.

Comment: Note if `item[1]` is some non-promise value `search_str`  is just going to be whatever `item[1]` is

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah yeah, i see. Deleted my comment.

Comment: _"item[1] is basically a string value and it looks for that string value inside the html"_ none of your code is searching for a string within the html text itself. You are parsing html into a document and then doing a query for elements that contain an attribute named `data-style-name`. Were you meaning to try to find elements that had an attribute of `data-style-name` with a specific value?

Comment: yes @PatrickEvans ,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of ways to achieve async request; with callbacks, promises and async/await. Using synchronous code is often interpreted as bad practice. From mdn:

> Note: Synchronous requests on the main thread can be easily disruptive to the user experience and should be avoided; in fact, many browsers have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely. Synchronous requests are permitted in Workers.

I use callbacks as an example here, which means you should supply `loadHTMLSource` with a callback to get the text;

```
function loadHTMLSource(urlSource, callback){ 
   xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("GET", urlSource);
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;
   xhttp.send();
   return;
}
```

Then get the response in cb:

```
loadHTMLSource(url, function(xhttp) {
    xhttp = xhttp.target; //note, we get event as parameter, target is xhr

    if(!xhttp.readyState === 4 && !xhttp.status === 200) {
        return;
    }

    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    var page_html = xhttp.responseText;
    parser = new DOMParser()
    my_document = parser.parseFromString(page_html, "text/html");

    //this only sets search_str as item[1]
    search_str = await item[1];
    search_attr_name = "data-style-name"; 

    var all_styles = my_document.querySelectorAll("[data-style-name]");
});
```

There are also a lot better ways to achieve asynchronous requests, such as [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and I highly suggest you take a look on those.

To use xhr with async/await, you need to promisify the xhr request:

```
function loadHTMLSource(urlSource){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", urlSource);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                //optional checks
                if(xhttp.responseText) {
                    return resolve(xhttp.responseText);
                }
                return reject();
            }
        }
        xhttp.send();
    });
}
```

For the `item[1]` and value looking part, your question needs more clarification

Comment: You didn't even answer my question, I want to do this with await and async

Comment: To make xhr available to await/async, you first need to promisify the xhr request, I'll add that to the answer soon

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: xhr is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onreadystatechange